# Why can't I see the Google login button?

Tags: android, google-signin

I have linked Google login to my 'JoinActivity'. Like this...

activity_join.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".JoinActivity">

<!--    this line-->
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btn.google"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But, I couldn't see any 'visual' button on my Design tab, there was only '200dp-linear button('cause its width values is 200dp. It doesn't have height value. idk why)' on the top-left.

I referenced other sites, videos. They all have visual button like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/844F2.png) but not me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, we can not see the icon in design mode, but it display when
> running the app.

Your XML has an error:

> This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it
> will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints

To make it work properly, we must add the constraint for horiziation and vertical.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btn.google"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And this is [constraint-layout introduction](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Try running Gradle, this sometimes triggers the design to redraw (if you have just added the google library without having ran Gradle fully)